# Getting Linked List to Print Out Numbers

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I want to fill a linked list with numbers provide by the user, and have them printed back out again. However my implementation, shown below, will only print out the first input number. I insert at the head of the list. Can you tell what is wrong?

```
struct Node 
{
  int data; 
  Node* next;
};

Node newNode(int num, Node *next_node)
{
    Node node;
    node.data = num;
    node.next = next_node;
    return node;
}

void headInsert(Node* head, int num)
{
    Node* tmp;  
    tmp  = new Node;
    tmp->data = num;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout<< "No input for linked list!! \n" <<
                    "Usage: ./linkedlist 2 3 567 12 .. etc."
                 <<"\n";
        return 0;
    }

    Node *head, *temp;
    head = new Node;
    head->data = atoi(argv[1]);
    head->next = NULL;

    headInsert(head, atoi(argv[2]));
    headInsert(head, atoi(argv[3]));

    temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL) 
    {
        std::cout << temp->data<< " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Since this is tagged as `C++`, why are you not using it?  I don't just mean `std::list`, but why not implement your list/node structure in an object-oriented way?  The use of `struct` with no member functions, and free functions to modify it is very much `C` like.  If this is an exercise on your own, at least I partially understand.  I pray that this is not the state of `C++` courses today though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insertion in linked list creating loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770543/insertion-in-linked-list-creating-loop)

Comment: It is the state of school courses, and I think it's a good thing.  God help you debugging a problem when you only understand a std::list.  You should understand how to make your own list with pointers before you use the freebie way that requires no knowledge.  Having said that, in production code you should definitely use the std:: implementations.

Comment: But what about this code is preparing students for practically working with C++?  Why not teach how to implement this in terms of an object with member functions?  Why doesn't a C++ course start with constructors/destructors immediately after "Hello World"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `headInsert()`, `head = tmp;` only changes the **local variable** `head`.

You could pass it as a **reference-to-pointer**, `Node*& head`.