# declaring a instance of a templte struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

i have the following node :

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
 };
```

i have to declare a instance of this listitem. i know how to declare a instance of a struct that is not a template like following:

```
node* x = new node;
 x = head; (or whatever)
```

now how do i do that here? if i follow the above procedure then i think i should do the following:

```
ListItem<T>* temp = new ListItem<T>;
```

but the compiler is giving the error that there is no function matching above line and ListItem expects 1 argument.
help quickly

Comment: Unless you're doing this for school (or something similar) where you need to follow this structure, I'd hide the `ListItem` inside a `List` (or whatever) class, such as shown in one a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10770700/179910).

Answer (score 2):

You have to pick a type to be your template argument, and pass a value to your constructor, since there is no default one. For instance, the equivalent of what you are doing with your non-template would be:

```
ListItem<double>* temp = new ListItem<double>(3.1416);
```

But this is doing more than just creating an instance. It is creating an instance with dynamic allocation, and initialiying a pointer to point to its location. How to "create an instance" would simply be

```
ListItem<double> temp(3.1416);
```

Be careful with raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects though. You should really be using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) here.

Note that you can provide a default constructor for your class too:

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem() : value(), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
    ListItem(T theVal) : value(theVal), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {}
 };
```

Note that I have changed your original constructor to use an initialization list, since that is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: what exactly did you do in this new constructor?

Comment: @khurramusman it *value* initializes `value`, which for primitive types means zero-initialize. I added the initialization of `next` and `prev`, which I had missed out before.

Comment: @khurramusman Ah, that was a type, sorry. I meant `value()`. It is fixed now.

Comment: ohh.... i understand it now. i am making a new contructor and go about that again. thaanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the constructor with a value!

Answer (score 1):

Constructing items in the form:

```
T* t = new T;
```

Uses the default constructor of `T`.  In your case, you've not provided a default constructor, and explicitly forbid the compiler from generating a default constructor since you have a constructor that takes a value.

Using that constructor takes the form:

```
T* t = new T(U);
```

To use a concrete example from your code:

```
// This will use the default constructor of ListItem<T>, which you _didn't_ provide
ListItem<T>* temp = new ListItem<T>;

// This will use single value constructor ListItem<int>(int), which you did provide.
ListItem<int>* temp = new ListItem<int>(7);

// The generic version would then be -- where T is actually default constructable
ListItem<T>* temp = new ListItem<T>(T());
```

For instance, adding a value to a linked list of type `int` requires that you know what value to add:

```
int value_to_add = 5;
ListItem<int>* temp = new ListItem<int>(value_to_add);
```

If you question is specifically about how to allocate the "head" node, this is typically a pointer to the first item in the list:

```
// pointer, does _not_ point to an instantiated value (yet)
ListItem<int>* head = nullptr;

// in the add function:
ListItem<int>* value = new ListItem<int>(value_to_add);

// if the list was empty...
if(nullptr == head)
   head = value;   // head now points to the first value
```

Comment: i know. but i dont know what to write there. this is a linked list as you can see. so i have to implement various functions. and for that i need to declare a node* in each function for adding deletion etc. should i make a new constructor?

Comment: When you add an item to a linked list, you need to know what _value_ you want to add.

Comment: so i need to declare a new generic constructor? the default constructor wont be useful because i dont know what T is going to be, so i cant by default make it equal to 0 like in case of int

Comment: I've updated the answer if you're confused specifically by the assignment of the "head" or "tail" values of the list (tail would work similarly to head)

Comment: what actually i am trying is to do that i want to make a temp node*. then i am going to make it equal to head. so i do not know a value in advance

Comment: "head" is a pointer, your temp node will be a pointer also.  You don't need to instantiate an instance of `ListItem<T>` to make them equal:  `ListItem<T>* temp = head;` is all you need.

Comment: @Chad i need to instantiate if i want to add a new node to the list.

Comment: If you want to add a new node to the list, then that node requires a value.  Why would you add a node to a linked list if you didn't already know what value would be used?

Comment: no actually my sir is going to be checking this using random codes that is different T classes. so i want to do this is most general form using only T and not using int or other data types

Comment: Sure, but generically, adding an element to a list implies that you know the value of the element you will be adding.  Otherwise, you have no element to add, be that `int` or `string` or `Foo`.